# CodeIgniter error 403 Access forbidden on Ubuntu

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu

I've been working on not-much-complicated projects using CodeIgniter on windows, but this is my first time to launch any php file in Ubuntu.

I copied a CodeIgniter project to `/opt/lampp/htdocs` which was working perfectly on windows but doesn't work on Ubuntu. It gave me the 403 error.

**Solved:**

1. Set permission from the command line:
   `sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs`

   then
   `sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/ PROJECT_FOLDER`

   where PROJECT_FOLDER is the name of your project directory.
2. Make sure your controllers' name are capitalized.

Comment: you need to give proper permission to your folder. give the permission using below command `chmod 777 -R PATH_OF_YOUR_PROJECT`

Comment: I gave the permission to the htdocs folder, that's how I became able to paste anything in there. do I have to do that for all the directories?

Comment: After copied the folder you have to give permission again to your project folder and using `-R` it will give permission to all inside folder also

Comment: Oh, I get it. when copying it I thought it would be given permission automatically. ok that got rid of the default 403 error but now it gave me the custom codeigniter's 404 error.

Comment: for that please If you have added **.htaccess than check your mod_rewrite is on or not or you can simply check with running with index,php** first. If it works correctly than you need to on `mod_rewrite` into your **php.ini** file.

Comment: tried and failed. every module is loaded in httpd.conf, also changed the `    AllowOverride none    ` to `    AllowOverride all    `

Comment: after changing your your server file you must need to restart your server. restart your server using this command `service apache2 restart` and check  `error_reporting` is on and put your error

Comment: apache2: unrecognized service 
but then I tried:
    sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
that restated it but no change.
 huh

Comment: @mzcoxfde its required 777 permeation on to folder. Better you run the project Via Virtual Host. Its get good result that LAMP.

Comment: While Raj is correct that this is a permissions problem, `chmod 777 -R PATH_OF_YOUR_PROJECT` is **very dangerous**. You've learnt a little about HTML, now you need to learn about permissions and work out a security model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the good comments, apache needs execute access on every folder from root to the project in order to traverse the file system.

```
sudo chmod +x /
sudo chmod +x /opt
sudo chmod +x /opt/lampp
```

Comment: Oh, yes that works. and I also completely forgot that Linux os are case sensitive. but the controllers were not capitalized. thanks guys